# How to take a linear combination of several dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python

Here's some code to take a linear combination of two dictionaries:

```
def linearcombination(a1,d1,a2,d2):
    return {k:a1*d1.get(k,0)+a2*d2.get(k,0) for k in {**d1,**d2}.keys()}


choosy1={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
choosy2={"a":1,"d":1}
choosy=linearcombination(1,choosy1,10,choosy2)
```

choosy is:

```
{'a': 11, 'c': 3, 'd': 10, 'b': 2}
```

How can I generalise it to allow linear combinations of arbitrary numbers of dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using `sum` in a dict comprehension over a set of keys:

```py
from itertools import chain

def linear_combination_of_dicts(dicts, weights):
    return {
        k: sum( w * d.get(k, 0) for d, w in zip(dicts, weights) )
        for k in set(chain.from_iterable(dicts))
    }
```

Example:

```py
>>> dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 1, 'd': 1}]
>>> weights = [1, 10]
>>> linear_combination_of_dicts(dicts, weights)
{'c': 3, 'd': 10, 'a': 11, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `pandas` to handle dict key alignment:

```
def lc(coeffs, dicts):
    return (pd.concat(pd.Series(d).fillna(0)*a for a,d in zip(coeffs,dicts))
              .sum(level=0)
              .to_dict()
           )

lc([1,10], [choosy1, choosy2])
# {'a': 11, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 10}
```